# Maximize xterm via bash script

Tags: xterm, escape-characters, window-management

I have found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/297176/93577) providing how to manipulate the current xterm window's dimensions, ie:

```
echo -ne "\e[8;30;30t"
```

How can I modify this to maximize the window (xterm's <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> shortcut)?

Also, where do I find more info on these xterm command line modifiers?

**UPDATE:**

See multiple solutions below for both maximize and full screen (without title and borders)

Comment: Take a look at xdotool, I'd use that method to do so. What you need should be in here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6001/7453

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The commands are

```
echo -ne '\e[9;1t'
```

to maximize and

```
echo -ne '\e[9;0t'
```

to restore the original size. It's described in the
[xterm control sequences documentation](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Uwe. I needed to use 10 for maximizing. I don't need to restore the size after. Actually, what yours does is spread the xterm window over all 3 of my windows, not just the monitor it is on.

Comment: Semantics, I had asked for "Maximize" which your answer I think is correct for. What I was looking for (kind of mentioned in question) was the shortcut for full screen, which is the `10` code. I'll award you the answer as it was first with the best information and leave mine for reference.

Answer (score 6):

The supplied answer from Uwe did not work for me, but this did:

```
echo -ne "\e[10;2;t"
```

From [this page](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html).